# Better understanding Services

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager

In the app I am working on, I have an `AlarmManager` that starts a `Service` at specified times and intervals. The `Service` uses some data I send in the `Intent` to read/write the SQLite database, make a `Notification` and send an SMS. I've had a problem that when the device goes into "deep sleep" and I use the device again, I get a force close with a `NullPointerException` on the `Intent` in the `Service`. As I've done some research, I've had several questions about how a `Service` works that I haven't been able to answer:

**1)** I realized that I was using the deprecated `onStart` method for a `Service`. I am going to switch to `onStartCommand` with `START_REDELIVER_INTENT` flag (think this was the null exception I was getting because the `Service` was trying to restart with the old `onStart` and not getting the original `Intent`). My question is this: Should I put the work the `Service` does in the `onStartCommand` or in `onCreate`? Is there any functional difference?

**2)** Considering what I am doing in my `Service`, is this enough work to put in its own `Thread`?

**3)** Do I need to specifically call `stopSelf`? If so, where is the best place to call it?

**4)** This one is more ambiguous: To my knowledge, I had canceled all of the alarms registered and after deep sleep, I still got the null exception for a `Service`. Is there any reason the `Service` would still get run even though I never triggered it with an alarm?

Please ask any clarifying question if necessary. I haven't posted code because most of it is generic for starting and consuming a `Service`, but if you want to have a peek, let me know. Thanks.

Comment: You should use IntentService instead of regular old Service. It does all its work in a background thread and stops itself automatically when it runs out of work

Comment: Looked into `IntentService` and it looks like it will be perfect. If you want to make this an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `IntentService` instead of regular old Service. It does all its work in a background thread and stops itself automatically when it runs out of work.